# How can I compile an IIFE JSX file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iife

I have been having trouble compiling a JSX file. A minimal example of my JSX file is a test.jsx:

```
(function()
    {
    })();
```

I run:

```
> jsx --output test.js test.jsx
```

And I get the following error message:

```
[test.jsx:1:0] expected keyword: class interface mixin abstract final native __fake__ __export__
(function()
^
```

JSX is:

```
> jsx --version
0.9.89 (2014-05-20 06:01:03 +0900; 8e8c6105f36f3dfe440ea026a3c93a3444977102)
```

What is the proper JSX wrapper (or other appropriate modification for an IIFE) for a JSX file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are two projects out there named JSX, and both being something you edit with and it is transformed into JavaScript. There are two separate repositories:

[Facebook's ReactJS, which includes one JSX, facebook.github.io/react](https://facebook.github.io/react/)

[A separate transpiled language meant to offer a better JavaScript, github.com/jsx](https://github.com/jsx/JSX/issues/332)

The comparison between the two is apples and oranges. I was running the second one with code written for the first, and erroring out. The error I got was after writing code for #1 and predictably getting errors after submitting it for #2.